# Installing Vue on windows getting depreciatted Error

Tags: node.js, windows, vue.js, windows-10

I'm new to Vue I planned to use vue in my next project just I was trying to setup the environment and I followed the instruction on the offical website, but i got some errors after running `npm instal -g @vue/cli` I try to search google for solution to the erro to no avail.
I'm trying to iunstall it on windows 10 and i already added the node js to my environment path
Anyone know how to solve this problem and why i get this problem please help me out.

```
node version: v16.13.1
 npm version: 8.3.0
 using: powershell 
      npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
    npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
    npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
    npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
    npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
    npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
    npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
    npm WARN deprecated graphql-extensions@0.15.0: The `graphql-extensions` API has been removed from Apollo Server 3. Use the plugin API instead: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/
    npm WARN deprecated apollo-tracing@0.15.0: The `apollo-tracing` package is no longer part of Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#tracing for details
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm WARN deprecated apollo-cache-control@0.14.0: The functionality provided by the `apollo-cache-control` package is built in to `apollo-server-core` starting with Apollo Server 3. 
    See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#cachecontrol for details.
    npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@4.0.8: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to 
    migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead        
    
    changed 942 packages, and audited 943 packages in 2m
    
    68 packages are looking for funding
      run `npm fund` for details
    
    11 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 7 high)
    
    Some issues need review, and may require choosing
    a different dependency.
    
    Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: Those are just warnings and it's up to the vue devs to update so you're good. Here's an old issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5690

Comment: @doesnotmatter how can I ignore those warning and procee with the installaion, because I try to proceed  and create vue project because after the warning error message no inditaction to continue with error and vue wasning install as well

Comment: is the log posted in OP the full-log? cause I didn't see anywhere it that it failed.